# Customizing a legend, bringing in a variable not graphed but summarized via geom_label

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a stacked bar chart which displays the average scores between two groups, by quarter. The graph includes two summary labels, the first is the total average score between the two groups and the second is a weighted average rate, which I include in the middle of each graph.

What I would like to do is customize my legend to include a third variable which would be a white box with a black border, reflecting the format of the weighted average rate. In doing so I would be able to label what this rate is. Is something you can do with `ggplot2`?

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(scales)
 library(dplyr)

df<-data.frame(Type=c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),Quarter=c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q1","Q2","Q3"),Score=c(1360.2565,1330.5412,1345.8975,1200.35478,1215.78945,1230.5167),WARate=c(.04,.0341,.0339,.04,.0341,.0339))

df%>%group_by((Quarter))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=(Quarter), y=Score,fill=Type))+
   geom_bar(stat = "identity")+scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)+
    geom_text(aes(label = format(round(stat(y),0),big.mark=","), group = Quarter), stat = 'summary', fun = sum, vjust = -.25)+
     geom_label(aes(label=format(round(WARate,2)), group = 1),stat='summary',fun=mean)+
       labs(title="Summary of Scores",x="Quarter",y="Average Scores",color="")+
         scale_fill_discrete(name="")
```

Comment: Your example is unfortunately not reproducible. For instance, what is `comma`? I strongly suggest you use `reprex::reprex()` to share a reproducible example. Also, it is not perfectly clear what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you can share some kind of hand-drawn expected output?

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up, `comma` is a function within the `scales` package. I updated my post to include the packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you are trying to achieve but you can use paste inside your label to add details about your summary values:

```r
df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=(Quarter), y=Score, fill=Type))+
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
    geom_text(aes(label=format(round(stat(y),0), big.mark=","), group=Quarter), stat='summary', fun = sum, vjust = -.25)+
    geom_label(aes(label=paste0("WARate mean:\n", format(round(WARate,2))), group = 1), stat='summary', fun=mean)+
    labs(title="Summary of Scores",x="Quarter",y="Average Scores",color="")+
    scale_fill_discrete(name="")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I didn't think about going this route but it works, thanks!